# Windows Phone 8: how to include image in sample photos?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, jpeg2000

I am testing a `PhotoChooserTask` based Windows Phone 8 application in an emulator. I want to test a specific image. Is it possible to somewhere add your own images to the sample photos that the emulator provides?

To be more specific, I want to test a library for decoding JPEG 2000 images, but it is not clear to me how to access arbitrary images on Windows Phone? `FileOpenPicker` compiles, but it throws a `NotSupportedException` when the constructor is invoked. The `PhotoChooserTask` is currently my best bet, but so far I have not been able to figure out to access images that are not part of the sample photos. And as far as I have been able to find out, [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) also does not provide a good enough answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upload the photo somewhere online, go to that URL in WP8 IE10, tap and hold and click "Save Picture". The picture should now be in your "Saved Pictures" folder which is visible in the PhotoChooserTask.

FileOpenPicker isn't currently supported on WP8. It's only useful for choosing photos from C++ code since PhotoChooserTask is a managed API and is unavailable to C++ apps. Read more about that here @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj215901(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Great idea! I'll try it out and let you know how it went.

Comment: As long as I have for example a regular JPEG file, your approach works fine. However, in my case I have a JPEG 2000 file, and I am not able to "fool" WP8 into saving this file. I have tried with valid file extension *.jp2* and also setting extension to *.jpg*, but in none of the cases the *Save picture* option can be obtained.

Comment: jp2 isn't a supported file format on WP8. Here's the list of file types supported by the WP8 OS @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207065(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Reservedfiletypes

Comment: Thanks for the link, Justin. However, I assume that it is still possible to develop WP applications that support other formats, such as *.jp2*? For example, will I be able to develop an application that access a *.jp2* file directly from an internet URI?