# How do I have a sample image available in WP7 emulator when my project runs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, image, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have a Windows Phone project compiled with 7.1 SDK. The application processes image files and I'd like to have a sample image file with the project so that when the project runs in the emulator and the user asks the application to open an image from the photo gallery (using `PhotoChooserTask`) my sample image somehow magically appears in the gallery and the user can select it.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14568697/57428) and I'm not completely sure it's about my scenario. That question OP wants to test his custom image. I want my custom image included into the project and then automagically appear in the emulator when someone gets my project from GitHub and opens it in Visual Studio and just runs it.

Is it possible to have a sample image included into WP 7.1 emulator when the project is being run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a blog post that explains how to have sample images in the emulator: http://www.softwareisinthedetails.com/2012/11/add-test-images-on-windows-phone-emulator.html

Comment: That code requires `Microsoft.Xna.Framework` and that's an extra non-trivial dependency. Is there any other way to save sample images?

Comment: As far is I know, the only way to programmatically save an image in the Media Library is via the MediaLibrary.SavePicture method.

Comment: I asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/16669010/57428 to clarify about possible problems. Looks like this solution is fine. Thanks a lot.