# Does using MediaLibrary class pose portability problems?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone project for SDK 7.1 (maybe I need to update it to use WP8 later) I want to add a test image into Windows Phone Emulator using [this code](http://www.softwareisinthedetails.com/2012/11/add-test-images-on-windows-phone-emulator.html). The latter uses `MediaLibrary` class and so I have to add a reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework`. No other code in my project needs that assembly.

I've found [this MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that says *You can use certain XNA Framework assemblies in apps that target Windows Phone OS 8.0.* and the list includes `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll`. So looks like I should not expect any problems but I'm not completely sure.

Will using `MediaLibrary` class and so having a reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework` cause any issues with portability of my code and its distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can safely use `MediaLibrary` and other permitted Xna assemblies in your WP8 projects. In fact, The [Rich media extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which adds certain extension methods to some classes in the Xna framework are exclusively available for WP8 only.